# Match a specific word while typing in input/contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, match

```
<div id="text" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

I have the above div and the below jQuery

```
$('#text').on('input', function() {
    if($(this).text() == 'banana') {
        alert('banana!');
    }
});
```

I need to search the value/text of **#text** every time you type something it should check if it can find "banana". Right now it's alerting if you have only typed "banana", but I need it to search through everything, even if there's other things typed there...for example:

```
<div id="text" contenteditable="true">
    damn, that's a tasty banana!
</div>
```

It should detect the "banana" in that.

Additionally, i will need to wrap (instead of alerting) that "banana" in something, like a span for example. Any thoughts on that? So final result should be something like:

```
<div id="text" contenteditable="true">
    damn, that's a tasty <span>banana</span>!
    and it even works with multiple <span>banana</span>s
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0n2phshs/)

#### HTML:

```
<div id="text" contenteditable="true">D</div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$('#text').on('input', function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    if($(this).text().match('banana') == 'banana') {
        alert('banana!');
    }
});
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks! Any ideas on wrapping said banana in a <span>?

Comment: Possibly something using :contains?